# Problem with export (download) into Excel-format with accented (central-european) charecters

Tags: php, excel, csv, export

I found and have read many answers here, but unfortunately none works for me. :(

So: I wanna export (and download) the array into Excel-format. Actually I try into CSV with .xls extension. But unfortunately only the following two cases occur:

- OR the accented letters are well, but the columns are not separated (tab char is like a "normal" char)
- OR the cell-separating is working, but the accented characters are wrong coded

I tried probably all the encodings, content-types, output-tpye (I mean bare echo, php://output, file-read etc.) with so many headers, but none of them works.

Comment: Meanwhile I found the solution: the separator character must be a semicolon (for. central-european excel)
Dear Admin, what should I do in this case?

Comment: So use the "," as the separator. What else do you expect? You have just told us it works.